# How to round values in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Please help me to round values (example: from 4.23 to 4 and 4.5 to 5). I have code such as below. I need do this on my frontend part:

```
              <p:column
                        styleClass="#{SomeClass.getAnotherSomething(row.magicCategory)}">
                    <h:outputLabel value="#{empty row.papaja ? 'N/A' : row.papaja}"
                                   styleClass="textChangesInCells"
                                   pt:data-selenium="papaja" />
                </p:column>
```

Comment: Why are you using `h:outputLabel`? Try `h:outputText` with `<f:convertNumber pattern="0"/>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `h:outputText` instead of `h:outputLabel`. With `h:outputText` you can use `f:convertNumber` to format a numeric value. With `format="0"` it'll round the value. So:

```
<h:outputText value="#{row.papaja}">
  <f:convertNumber pattern="0"/>
</h:outputText>
```

To handle `'N/A'`, you need to do a check using `c:if`, `c:choose`, or use `rendered` attributes.